# Looping dates dynamically inside a function with Python

Tags: python, function, api, loops, date

I'm making a call to an API but the API will only provide me one year of data at a time.  But I would like to use a loop to pull in more than just one year of data.

I have the following start and end date in a range:

```
startdate = datetime.date(2011, 9, 6)
enddate = datetime.date(2014, 10, 12)
```

I have a long function written (not shown here) and use the following code to call the function and pass in the arguments:

```
get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (startdate, enddate, lat, long, fields = None)
```

**How do I write the following large chunk of code below inside a looping function? ...it must be in function format.**  In the code below, instead of listing out each start and end date explicitly, I want those values to be derived dynamically based on the 'startdate' and 'enddate' variables I provided above. **How can I do that?**

```
WSI_Hourly = get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (datetime.date(2011, 9, 6), datetime.date(2011, 12, 31), 39.742721,-105.0816042, fields=None)
WSI_Hourly1 = get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2012,12,31), 39.742721,-105.0816042, fields=None)
WSI_Hourly = WSI_Hourly.append(WSI_Hourly1,ignore_index=True)
WSI_Hourly1 = get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (datetime.date(2013,1,1), datetime.date(2013,12,31), 39.742721,-105.0816042, fields=None)
WSI_Hourly = WSI_Hourly.append(WSI_Hourly1,ignore_index=True)
WSI_Hourly1 = get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (datetime.date(2014,1,1), datetime.date(2014,10,12), 39.742721,-105.0816042, fields=None)
WSI_Hourly = WSI_Hourly.append(WSI_Hourly1,ignore_index=True)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just find years between startdate and enddate

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime1, datetime2):
    #YOUR CODE HERE

def my_wrapper_func(startdate, enddate):
    middle_years = range(startdate.year+1, enddate.year)
    _all = []
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31)))
    for year in middle_years:
        _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(year, 1, 1), datetime(year, 12, 31)))
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31)))
    return _all

my_wrapper_func(datetime(2010, 2, 1), datetime(2015, 2,1))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I am getting the following error: invalid syntax for : 'for year in middle_years:'  the error pointer carrot points to the ':' part of that line of code    ...thoughts?

Comment: when I run the above code I get the following error: "    TypeError: get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lat' and 'long'   "    ; I tried placing in the lat long arguments myself but it errored out....I'm not sure if I put them in the right places  ...thoughts?

Comment: putting them in the order you defined in the function should get no errors, you might want to check your function definition again

Comment: when I run my function and the run the following code it executes successfully...so I think my function is fine:     WSI_Hourly = get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (datetime.date(2015,1,1), datetime.date(2015,2,1), 41.0340, 73.7629, fields = None)     ...thoughts?

Comment: In `my_wrapper_func` you also have to assign parameters in the argument list as the definition in your `get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical`. The above code just show you an example of how to loop over the datetime you want and it has nothing to do with your function. Just replace the function to your one and add the required parameters and it should work fine. If not, update your post with your code so I can debug your problem.